# Magento 2 Product Price for multiple store is not correct

Tags: magento2, price, tax, tax-calculation

I am using 2 stores,

**Main/Default** store is working fine but in second store, the price I am giving to product is not showing accurate.

In frontend it calculate and showing price by using this formula:

> (actual_price / default_store_tax ) * current_store_tax

I want to display actual price in frontend which I am adding in backend.

In my configuration I am showing price including tax.

Please guide me.

Comment: This doesn't worked. I found the solution , am posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed to change country in Shipping setting,

> Under Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Settings

fields mentioned in image was wrong, after changing it issue solved!

[image]